# how to convert a non-static value to a static value in android

Tags: java, android, static, non-static

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "AdmissionsPrefs" ;

final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

String server = settings.getString(ConfigureServer.SERVER, "");


public static final String HOMEURL = "http://**10.0.2.2**/Admission/index.php?r=";

public static final String USERID = "user_id";

public static final String CONTACTS = "contacts";
```

How to use the value from the shared preferences **server**(Non-static) in the **HOMEURL** at **10.0.2.2**(static) .....

Comment: Um, you can't. There could be multiple different instances of your class, each with a different server - which would you expect to use? It sounds like your `HOMEURL` shouldn't be static...

Comment: You should look up what the keywords `static` and `final` do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing you  can replace on runtime.

```
private static final String HOME_URL = "http://%s/Admission/index.php?r=";

String builtUrl = String.format(HOME_URL, "10.0.2.2");
```

The "%s" in the url is replaced with the ip and returned in builtUrl variable.

> Note: HOME_URL wont be changed, so use builtUrl